# JSON REST request with PHP response as variable

Tags: php, json, rest

I am trying to get the following request on headers Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

```
{
  "userVO": {
     "userId": "899",
    "lstAuthToken":" uYCpPz6LTYVAZBee8S2cy5ZwFk%3D"
    }
}
```

sent to the URL of the following: http://54.84.41.76/wkconnects/rest/manageLST/validateLSTAuthToken for validation.
I will get the response of:

```
{
  "ccVerified": "true",
  "sessionAuthenticationToken": "KAA93bndyYaVPCVa8Sx%2FqLomPUP0CSBVHLRBQKMy3e9N%2FnYBEdjXHoN0lmxLfRwljH3PpkeOLIYS%0AQ4WVhF14015bz22HOAq%2B%2FBzMfzI3Z3jFmcuPDhZ6UGGv691Q1azHuQq8U7Biz8DSkPZV0qznohjD%0A43AhVR03LLFcffHI3do%3D",
  "status": "true"
}
```

I need to get the response ccVerifiedand sessionAuthenticationToken as variables so I can say =true or =false etc.

I tried using the following with little success:

```
<?php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get('http://54.84.41.76/wkconnects/rest/manageLST/generateLSTAuthToken', [
    'auth' =>  ['899', 'uYCpPz6LTYVAZBeH9Xfi%2F2cy5ZwFk%3D']
]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();           // 200
echo $res->getHeader('content-type'); // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $res->getBody();                 // {"type":"User"...'
var_export($res->json());     
?>
```

Comment: you forgot to tell us what the problem is!

Comment: and you shouldn't post a real authToken here. Please refresh it _now_.

Comment: empty page response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry im doing stuff like this mostly with curl

```
<?php                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode(["userVO" => ['userId' => 899, 'lstAuthToken' => 'token']]);                                                                                                                           
    $ch = curl_init('http://54.84.41.76/wkconnects/rest/manageLST/generateLSTAuthToken');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)]);                                                                                                                   
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    if($result->status == "true"){
        $lstAuthToken = $result->lstAuthToken;
        $sessionAuthenticationToken = $result->sessionAuthenticationToken;
    }
    else{
        echo "something went wrong";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: AMAZING YOU ROCK STEFAN!

Comment: On a side note, how would that type of response be able to help with determine whether to send someone to a credit card failure, or cc success page?

Comment: btw im not sure, i can send this req withouth any token and get a true back

Comment: i dont understand what u mean but u can do print_r($result) and get everything u get as result

Comment: The value for "lsttokenauth" will be dynamic.

Comment: sure but seems like i can send whatever i like, anyway ur question is marked whatever this service is for

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks.